# Python: how to check if an item was added to a set, without 2x (hash, lookup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I was wondering if there was a clear/concise way to add something to a set and check if it was added without 2x hashes & lookups.

this is what you might do, but it has 2x hash's of item

```
if item not in some_set:  # <-- hash & lookup
    some_set.add(item)    # <-- hash & lookup, to check the item already is in the set

    other_task()
```

This works with a single hash and lookup but is a bit ugly.

```
some_set_len = len(some_set)
some_set.add(item)
if some_set_len != len(some_set):

    other_task()
```

Is there a better way to do this using Python's set api?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the issue is `other_task()`.

Comment: Maybe you will have to implement your own set class.

Comment: The `add` method already do this test for you, so just call it.

Comment: @DSM, the OP is comparing lengths of sets just adding won't make a difference

Comment: Lookups are very cheap for `set`, you really shouldn't worry about an extra `item in some_set`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: you're missing the OP's point.  The OP wants to do something -- call `other_task()` -- *if the element isn't already in the set*, which means he needs to know if it is.  He's worried (unnecessarily, in my view) about the performance impacts of the repeated lookup, but simply saying "just add it" isn't relevant.

Comment: If this is important for your application then I don't see anything wrong with the second approach.

Comment: @DSM, the OP has a working alternative where they are just adding it, it may well be pointless as lookups are 0(1) but it is a working alternative

Comment: @Cyber, lookups are fast, but reducing lookups will almost certainly be faster, and hash functions aren't guaranteed to be fast for all object types (even if they should be in an ideal scenario).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. You could, of course, write  your own function:

```
def do_add(s, x):
  l = len(s)
  s.add(x)
  return len(s) != l

s = set()
print(do_add(s, 1))
print(do_add(s, 2))
print(do_add(s, 1))
print(do_add(s, 2))
print(do_add(s, 4))
```

Or, if you prefer cryptic one-liners:

```
def do_add(s, x):
  return len(s) != (s.add(x) or len(s))
```

(This relies on the left-to-right evaluation order and on the fact that `set.add()` always returns `None`, which is falsey.)

All this aside, I would only consider doing this if the double hashing/lookup is demonstrably a performance bottleneck *and* if using a function is demonstrably faster.

Comment: +=1, but cryptic oneliner just *has* to be a `lambda` for extra unreadability.

Comment: `lambda l,I:l.__len__()!=(l.add(I)or l.__len__())`

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries have the nice [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function to avoid a whole class of problems related to the "double lookup" mentioned in the question. Since, in CPython at least, most of the set code is shared with dictionaries, I tried using that when working with a very large set (500k+ add, +/- 10% duplicates entries).

In addition, in order to reduce the overhead implied by the Python symbol name lookup, I wrapped that in a higher-order function so the compiler will build a closure and so will be able to use the index-based [`LOAD_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST)/[`LOAD_DEREF`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF) opcodes instead of the more expensive name lookup based [`LOAD_ATTR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_ATTR)/[`LOAD_GLOBAL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL):

```
def cache():
  s = {}
  setdefault = s.setdefault
  n = 0

  def add(x):
    nonlocal n
    n+=1
    return setdefault(x,n) != n

  return add


# Usage
cached = cache()

for i in my_large_generator_with_duplicates():
  if not cached(i):
    do_something()
```

In *my particular use case*, this solution runs more than 20% faster than the one suggested in the other answer. Of course, your mileage may vary, so you should run your own tests.

---

For reference, here are the disassembled code of both solution (Python3.5 running on Linux):

```
def do_add(s, x):
  l = len(s)
  s.add(x)
  return len(s) != l


dis.dis(do_add)

 20           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)                                                                                                                                                                    
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)                                                                                                                                                                      
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)                                                                                                                                           
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (l)                                                                                                                                                                      

 21          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)                                                                                                                                                                      
             15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (add)                                                                                                                                                                    
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)                                                                                                                                                                      
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)                                                                                                                                           
             24 POP_TOP                                                                                                                                                                                             

 22          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)                                                                                                                                                                    
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)                                                                                                                                                                      
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             34 LOAD_FAST                2 (l)
             37 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
```

```
def cache():
  s = {}
  setdefault = s.setdefault
  n = 0

  def add(x):
    nonlocal n
    n+=1
    return setdefault(x,n) != n

  return add


dis.dis(cache.__code__.co_consts[2])


 13           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD
              7 STORE_DEREF              0 (n)

 14          10 LOAD_DEREF               1 (setdefault)
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             16 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
             25 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
```